Run Camel K jdbc locally with JBang
I'm trying to run camel-k with jdbc locally with the following configuration.
Integration DSL KamelKJdbcRouter.java:
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

// camel-k: dependency=camel:jdbc
// camel-k: dependency=mvn:io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-postgresql

public class KamelKJdbcRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer://foo?period=10000")
                .setBody(constant("SELECT data FROM test LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0"))
                .to("jdbc:default")
                .to("log:info");
    }

}

application.properties:
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/test
quarkus.datasource.username=postgresadmin
quarkus.datasource.password=admin123
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql

Command:
jbang run -Dcamel.jbang.version=4.2.0 camel@apache/camel run KamelKJdbcRouter.java

But I get following error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No default DataSource found in the registry
        at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcComponent.createEndpoint(JdbcComponent.java:67)
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:170)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doGetEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:804)
        ... 34 more

It seems like quarkus build isn't kicking in and the datasource is not being created.
The example works fine on k8s.
I'm using camel-k with jbang with other components (like activemq) and they work fine.
Do you have any idea? Thanks!

camel-jbang does not understand quarkus specific connection pools and whatnot. However this may be something we can add to camel-jbang for a common feature like databases etc.
You can configure a generic datasource as a bean and let camel-jbang use that until we have something for camel-jbang OOTB.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-20681

Adding the datasource bean works fine. Yeah, having it out of the box would be cool, thanks.

In Camel 4.6 you can run this directly in quarkus via
camel run * --runtime=quarkus
And it will automatic detect dependencies so you dont need that camel-k stuff in the top
